# How can I format this using StringBuilder

Tags: java, android, stringbuilder

I have got the user city, state and country from the geocoder. In this format as below

```
D/ProfileFrg: StateName: Pune, Maharashtra 411053
D/ProfileFrg: CountryName: India
```

I want to format this String using StringBuilder into Single Line: **Pune, Maharashtra, India** which the zip code will be removed.

I haven't used StringBuilder before I am new to it can anyone help with the solution to this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html

Comment: Why do you think you should use `StringBuilder`? Rather than, say, `Formatter`? Or `String.replace`{,`All`}?

Comment: @AndyTurner how can I use it in my case? To remove the zipcode ?

Answer (score 0):

```
   A better snippet would be as below.

String abc = "D/ProfileFrg: StateName: Pune, Maharashtra 411053" + "D/ProfileFrg: CountryName: India";
        /* split results with below output.
         * D/ProfileFrg StateName Pune, Maharashtra 411053D/ProfileFrg
         * CountryName India
         */
        String[] x = abc.split(":");

        String y = x[2] + ", " + x[4];
        /* y is Pune, Maharashtra 411053D/ProfileFrg, India */

        String[] z = y.split(" ");
        /* z has Pune, Maharashtra 411053D/ProfileFrg,
         * India
         */
        String finalValue = z[1] + " " + z[2] + ", " + z[5];
        System.out.println(finalValue);
```

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=2 @ String y = x[2] + ", " + x[4];

Comment: Please note that I am splitting abc text which is  String abc = "D/ProfileFrg: StateName: Pune, Maharashtra 411053" + "D/ProfileFrg: CountryName: India";

Comment: It has bothe lines  D/ProfileFrg: StateName: Pune, Maharashtra 411053 and 
D/ProfileFrg: CountryName: India

Answer (score 0):

Well I have found the solution to replace the numbers from the String.

```
String place = stateName + countryName;
        place  = place.replaceAll("[0-9]","");
        Log.d(TAG, place);
```